# Contact form submit, having to click twice

Tags: forms, mobile

I am having an issue with different contact forms (I've tried a few) on mobile devices. The issue being that you have to click submit twice.

The first time you click the text grey's out a bit like placeholder text but is still typable. It does nothing else until clicked again.

I have only tested on Firefox mobile so far.

Comment: how is the form implemented? can we see code? can we see an example? I don't know how anyone is going to provide an answer with the info provided.

Comment: The problem can be causes by some code conflict. Try removing any position: absolute; in your code to see if it fixes it.

Comment: show the code for those forms and related css

Comment: Firefox mobile is not a standard device browser and has some known issues. Try a stock browser (the one that comes with the device) and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a 'classic *rollover effect* bug' to me: if you trigger a visual effect on any link (or 'button') either with jQuery or JavaScript, users on touch devices may be forced to click twice: "[iPad/iPhone hover problem causes the user to double click a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link)"

I suggest you either try to replace the 'mouseover' effects with css :hover effects or trigger the jQuery event only, if the user is *not* on a touch device.

A third way can be found on the page over at stackexchange that I linked above: add a jquery snippet that tells the (iOS) browser the link was actually clicked.

PS: it could be useful anyways if you could either provide code or name any of the contact form plugins you used.